# Drupal is looking for a field that no longer exists

Tags: sql, database, drupal, phpmyadmin

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sites/superallan.com/public_html/includes/common.inc:2561) in drupal_send_headers() (line 1040 of /home/sites/superallan.com/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'web247-sa_admin.field_data_field_embedcode' doesn't exist: SELECT field_data_field_embedcode0.entity_type AS entity_type, field_data_field_embedcode0.entity_id AS entity_id, field_data_field_embedcode0.revision_id AS revision_id, field_data_field_embedcode0.bundle AS bundle FROM {field_data_field_embedcode} field_data_field_embedcode0 WHERE (field_data_field_embedcode0.deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (field_data_field_embedcode0.bundle = :db_condition_placeholder_1) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => blog ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() (line 569 of /home/sites/superallan.com/public_html/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

As I understand it Drupal is looking for a data field that I deleted. I thought maybe it had got corrupted and Drupal couldn't find it to delete it properly. In phpMyAdmin  it doesn't exist so how can I get Drupal to recognize it's not longer there and stop it showing this error at the bottom of every page?

You can see it on this page: http://superallan.com/404

Comment: How did you 'delete' the field in the first place?

Comment: I added it to the content type - put in a small text field, put a huge character limit on it, drupal gave me an error, so I then deleted it from the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the site cache, or uninstalling the module that provides the field?  It looks like a reference to the field's SQL data is sticking around in your database, which is of course causing the error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
DELETE FROM `field_config` WHERE `deleted` = 1;
DELETE FROM `field_config_instance` WHERE `deleted` = 1;

I received no adverse effect from removing all the things that were already deleted.

Source:
http://digcms.com/remove-field_deleted_data-drupal-database/